# Replacing a few sensitive characters in fields with XXX-masked fields in UNIX

Tags: csv, unix

I have a table which has been exported to a file in UNIX which has data in CSV format like for e.g.:

File 1:

```
ACCT_NUM,EXPIRY_DT,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
123456,09-09-2019,Prisi,Kumar
```

Now I need to mask ACCT_NUM and FIRST_NAME and replace the masked values in File 1, the output should look something like this

File 2:

```
ACCT_NUM,EXPIRY_DT,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
123XXX,09-09-2019,PRXXX,Kumar
```

I have separate masking functions for numerical and string fields, I need to know how to replace the masked columns in the original file.

Comment: What are the masking functions? This is underspecified: always 3 XXX from the right? Or everything after the third ACCT_NUM digit? What tools are you willing to use (sed, awk, perl, ...)? And most importantly, what have you tried so far?

Comment: It is not about the masking functions, i need to know how to replace the original columns with the masked columns,i have tried several commands with awk and sed, but none of it seemed to work..

Comment: Tried this command to replace the column but it did not work,'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$3;next}{$2=a[FNR]}1' f2 f1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do with `FNR` and what the point of assigning to array `a` should be. This is how I would do it:

```
$ cat x.awk
#!/bin/sh

awk -F, -vOFS=, '  # Set input and output field separators.
NR == 1 {          # First record?
   print           # Just output.
   next            # Then continue with next line.
}

NR > 1 {                      # Second and subsequent record?
   if (length($1) < 4) {      # Short account number?
       $1 = "XXX"             # Replace the whole number.
   } else {
       sub(/...$/, "XXX", $1) # Change last three characters.
   }
   if (length($3) < 4) {      # Short first name number?
       $3 = "XXX"             # Replace the whole name.
   } else {
       sub(/...$/, "XXX", $3) # Change last three characters.
   }
   print                      # Output the changed line.
}'
```

Showtime!

```
$ cat input
ACCT_NUM,EXPIRY_DT,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
123456,09-09-2019,Prisi,Kumar
123,29-12-2017,Jim,Kirk
$ ./x.awk < input
ACCT_NUM,EXPIRY_DT,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
123XXX,09-09-2019,PrXXX,Kumar
XXX,29-12-2017,XXX,Kirk
```